# How to run .Net core application on linux without wine?

Tags: linux, .net

I have .Net Core WPF application in **.exe** format I didn't publish for linux because I am not getting those publish option for WPF, so is it possible to run it on Linux without wine? If yes then how?

Answer (score 2):

As per this answer in [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/950270/can-i-run-net-6-0-wpf-app-on-linux) from Aug 2022 WPF is not cross-platform, but "you can, theoretically, run it using Wine".

Comment: I read that, but I wanted to know if there is any by-pass or something. Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean "I read that before asking"? Maybe it'd be good idea to check [how to write a good question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help). You should put the relevant info directly into your question. Even after you've posted it, you can always [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/734671/edit) it afterwards to add more info or clarify the question. This way everything relevant to your situation is directly available for the community members. This way you don't get suggestions you've already tried.